# How to show different APIs data in one table

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which I am showing data from two different APIs:-

```
<label>USER CODE:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="a.code"/>  

<button type="button" ng-click="getData(a.code)">Show</button>

<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Staff/Customer Code</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in allUsers track by $index" >
         <td>{{row}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

scope.getData = function (code) {
      ApiServices.getStaff(code).then(function (response) {
            scope.assignedStaff = response.data;
            scope.allUsers = scope.assignedStaff;
      });
      ApiServices.getCustomers(code).then(function (response) {
            scope.assignedCustomers = response.data;
            scope.allUsers = scope.assignedCustomers;
      });
};
```

What I am doing is when I type any staff code and press show button `getStaff` api is called and when I type customer code and press show button `getCustomers` api is called. Since, the response is an array I am showing it in table with ng-repeat. For `getStaff` I am getting null array as its calling `getCustomers` after that which will return null. But its working fine for `getCustomers`. What should I do so that `getCustomers` won't call after `getStaff` hence won't show the null array.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you combine the array in `ng-repeat` using `concat`

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Staff/Customer Code</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in allUsers = assignedStaff.concat(assignedCustomers) track by $index" >
         <td>{{row}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

scope.getData = function (code) {
      ApiServices.getStaff(code).then(function (response) {
            scope.assignedStaff = response.data;
      });
      ApiServices.getCustomers(code).then(function (response) {
            scope.assignedCustomers = response.data;
      });
};
```

Comment: I don't want combined array. I want to show them separately.

Comment: according to your code, you replace the values assign to the array depend on the which request resolve last

Comment: Yes, I am replacing  the array, I don't want it combined. Is there any way to do it with replacing array.

Comment: but how do recognize which service call do you want to replace it with

Comment: allUsers = assignedStaff when getStaff is called and allUsers = assignedCustomers when getCustomers is called. The user code which user types is sent in both the apis, but only one will return the response. That response should be visible in the table.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have some categorization to identify which is the `Staff code` and which is the `Customer code` like **:**

```
Staff Code : STAFXXXXXX
Customer Code : CUSTXXXXXX
```

Hence, inside `getData` function you can check the index of the code passed on click of `show` and based on the categorization chars(`Like : STAF & CUST`) you can call the specific API.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.getData = function(code) {
      if (code.indexOf('STAF') != '-1') {
        console.log("Staff API call");
      } else if (code.indexOf('CUST') != '-1') {
        console.log("Customer API call");
      } else {
        console.log("No API call");
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <label>USER CODE:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="code"/>
  <button type="button" ng-click="getData(code)">Show</button>
</div>
```